# Why does there appear text on my command line even though I've redirected both STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, redirect, debian, fuse

I'm trying to unmount a encfs-filesystem from a script, but no matter how I try I seem unable to prevent the fuse error below to appear on screen/in crontab emails.

```
# exec 3>&1 1>/dev/null 4>&2 2>/dev/null; setsid fusermount -u /data/encfs; exec 1>&3 2>&4 3>&- 4>&-
# fuse failed.  Common problems:
 - fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
 - invalid options -- see usage message
```

The error itself I have to live with. The unmount is successfull and the error is false and due to a bug that is long gone in modern versions of fuse. I'm stuck with the older version since I'm on special hardware running a semi-ancient version of debian.

What annoys me is that I cannot tell the system to toss the nonsense message in /dev/null.
How does the message even appear on my screen after me using both setsid and redirects in my best efforts to prevent it?

EDIT:

```
# exec 3>&1 1>/dev/null 4>&2 2>/dev/null; setsid fusermount -u /data/encfs > /dev/null 2>&1; EXIT=$?; exec 1>&3 2>&4 3>&- 4>&-; echo $EXIT
0
# fuse failed.  Common problems:
 - fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
 - invalid options -- see usage message
```

I've even tried things like:

```
perl -e "`fusermount -u /data/encfs`"
```

But the error remain the same.

My /etc/syslog.conf:

```
auth,authpriv.*                     -/var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv,cron.none         -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                              -/var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                              -/var/log/user.log

*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    mail.none       -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail.none       -/var/log/messages
```

EDIT2:

I don't think fusermount is the program actually generating the text. It pokes something else that does:

```
# strace -o ~/trash/strace.txt fusermount -u /data/encfs; EXIT=$?; echo $EXIT; grep write ~/trash/strace.txt                             
fuse failed.  Common problems:
 - fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
 - invalid options -- see usage message
0
write(5, "/dev/hdc1 / ext3 rw,noatime 0 0\n", 32) = 32
write(5, "proc /proc proc rw 0 0\n", 23) = 23
write(5, "devpts /dev/pts devpts rw 0 0\n", 30) = 30
write(5, "sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0\n", 24) = 24
write(5, "tmpfs /ramfs ramfs rw 0 0\n", 26) = 26
write(5, "tmpfs /USB tmpfs rw,size=16k 0 0"..., 33) = 33
write(5, "/dev/c/c /c ext3 rw,noatime,acl,"..., 65) = 65
write(5, "nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd nfsd rw 0 0\n", 31) = 31
write(5, "usbfs /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw 0 0"..., 33) = 33
write(5, "//localhost/smb /root/folder"..., 55) = 55
```

If I let strace log to stdout I get the error message in the middle of the umount system call:

```
# strace fusermount -u /data/encfs
execve("/usr/bin/fusermount", ["fusermount", "-u", "/data/encfs"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
[... abbreviating ...]
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0x20020000, 16384)               = 0
profil(0, 0, 0x2010c168, 0x4)           = 0
umount("/data/encfs", 0fuse failed.  Common problems:
 - fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)
 - invalid options -- see usage message
)    = 0
profil(0, 0, 0x1177c, 0x20179f98)       = 0
stat64("/etc/mtab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=407, ...}) = 0
ftime(0x13840)                          = 0
```

Comment: Maybe this message comes from syslog...

Check if you have a line like `*.emerg   *` in your /etc/syslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.conf

Comment: What about `setsid fusermount -u /data/encfs >/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: Have you tried something like `{ fusermount -u /data/encfs ; } &> /dev/null` ?

Comment: If you have another terminal window open, does the error also appear on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The error message does not come from the fusermount, it comes from the mount command when fusermount runs.

Doing it like this fixes the problem:

```
# encfs --extpass=echo_key.sh /data/.encfs /data/encfs 2>/dev/null; sleep 3; fusermount -u /data/encfs
#
```

Feels so obvious now that I know...

Answer (score 2):

Use `strace` on the command. It will show you details about what's going on, including the number of the descriptor to which the message is written

```
strace fsusermount -u /data/encfs
```

If the message comes from `fsusermount` you should see a line like

```
write(0, "- fuse kernel module not installed (modprobe fuse)\n")
```

somewhere in the output. The number (not necessarily 0) is the number of the file descriptor to which the message is written. Redirecting the descriptor with that number should get you rid of the message:

```
fsusermount -u /data/encfs 0>/dev/null
```